# Moving Component With SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, position, swingworker

I'm currently trying to get a `JLabel` to move across the screen using a `SwingWorker.` I can get the `JLabel` to update the text in the `SwingWoker` but I can't make it change its position.

Here is what I have currently tried

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;

public class MainFrame
{
    public MainFrame()
    {
        addComponents();
    }

    public void addComponents()
    {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Some Frame");
        JLabel enemyLabel = new JLabel("Enemy");
        mainFrame.add(enemyLabel);

        moveEnemies(enemyLabel, mainFrame);

        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void moveEnemies(JLabel label, JFrame frame)
    {
        SwingWorker<Void, Integer> enemyMover = new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>()
        {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    int x = 50 * i;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    publish(x);
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<Integer> chunks)
            {
                label.setSize(50, 50);
                for(int num : chunks)
                {
                    label.setText(String.valueOf(num));
                    label.setLocation(num, 250);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void done()
            {
                label.setText("Finished");
            }
        };
        enemyMover.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(MainFrame::new);
    }
}
```

I've also printed out the `JLabel.getLocation()` and it prints the expected position, [250, 250] at the end of the loop, but the position doesn't change on the screen. I've also tried to `revalidate()`, & `repaint()` but neither seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're fighting the frame's default layout manager (`BorderLayout`) which would very much like to keep the label where it thinks it should be.

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

To "fix" the "immediate" problem, you "could" set the layout manager for the frame to `null`, but this will open a can of very vicious and nasty worms.  A better solution would be to stop using components in this way and use custom painting to render the text within a component.

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details.

While it's possible to do some interesting animation with Swing components, there's a lot to take into consideration. If you're just creating a game of some kind, then it's better to use a custom painting based approach

Comment: I did try to set the layout to `null` earlier with no luck. But I guess I will have to give the custom painting an approach (I was afraid of that). But it's always good to learn new things.

Comment: You don't seem to be adjusting for the job that the layout manager would otherwise do, setting the size of the component for example

Comment: I set the size and set the layout to `null` and it worked. Based on your recommendations, I'm going to give custom painting a go. Thanks for the help! :)